# How can I now claim the benefits if I forgot to submit a W8?

Tags: united-states, irs, student, form-w-8-ben

I'm an international grad student in the US, and according to the tax treaty the US has with my country, my fellowship is tax exempt. However, I forgot to file the W8 form with my university, so for 2018, they have withheld all my taxes.

How can I now claim the benefits of my tax treaty? Will the amount withheld be automatically returned by the IRS?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to wait until 2019, file a tax return, and claim the exemption there. You should get a refund.